# Wrong Condition code from Yahoo Weather

Tags: yahoo-weather-api

I am using the Yahoo Weather API to get forecast on my website but I've noticed that the "scattered showers" code is 39 instead of 40 and "scatttered thunderstorms" is 47 instead of 37 or 38 as indicated on Yahoo's documentation.

It seems that it is not just a recent bug. But I couldn't find any updated condition list.

Comment: Can you provide an example to what your request/response looks like from yahoo?  Could be a bug on their end if it doesn't match the documentation like it should

Answer (score 0):

I think yahoo has noticed this bug and might be working on it.

I tried playing around with their developer network api trying to pull the various condition codes and had no luck.  Then I finally found this which is where they store the gifs for the weather condition codes and on there it is incorrect as well.  Yet when you go to their main page it says that "Yahoo! Will be right back...Our Engineers are working quickly to resolve the issue.

```
http://l.yimg.com/

http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/40.gif 
http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/39.gif - Both give scattered rainshowers 

http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/37.gif 
http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/38.gif - Both give isolated thunderstorms
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like yahoo engineers do not work quickly enough - or just never worked on it ;)

```
{
    "query": {
        "count": 1,
        "created": "2017-09-06T09:47:17Z",
        "lang": "en",
        "results": {
            "channel": {
                "item": {
                    "condition": {
                        "code": "39",
                        "date": "Wed, 06 Sep 2017 10:00 AM CEST",
                        "temp": "62",
                        "text": "Scattered Showers"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

official documentation lists 39 as `scattered thunderstorms`
https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/documentation.html